# how to pass value to @POST annotation from any method as path or url i.e such as @POST("/url") to @POST(getURL()) in android

Tags: android, c++, post, retrofit

how to pass value  to @POST annotation  from any method as path or url   i.e such as @POST("/url") to @POST(getURL()) in android

To hide my URL i want to pass value from method not hard code it  such like @POST("\v3\url")/ it take only constant value .

i want to hide my all url in native C++ code to make harder to decompile  APP hide sensitive data in hard code. 
1. Is There any way or it allow to pass value to POST/GET... from method?
2. Can we Override  it ?

Sorry in advanced for poor English

Comment: i have done something like this `@POST("series.php/"+RetrofitClient.API_KEY)` is this you want ?

Comment: i know i can use it as RetrofitClient.API_KEY i get value from native method such as     public static native String getUrl(); and want to use it as @POST(a,getUrl())

Comment: i use @URL and it work for me .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Retrofit path parameters, e.g.

```
@GET("{aaa}")
Call<Whatever> a(@Path("aaa") String aaa);
```

And when you want to call this api call it like this:

```
api.a(<a c++ native call that returns path>);
```

Also if your data is extremely important you can add some custom encryptions alongside which famous encryptions like AES, etc.

PS: I recommend to use an asymmetric encryption method too.